# Webmin Linux Email configuration

Tags: email, postfix

This is probably a trivial question, however, if I have a user in Linux address say for example: **sales**

And I host multiple domains say: **example.com** and **example2.com**

How do I ONLY have the mail delivered to sales if it is sent to **sales@example.com** and **not sales@example2.com**?

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of a cheap answer, but ... you could use [Virtualmin](http://www.webmin.com/vdownload.html).  It's overkill if email separation is all you want, but it'll make managing a range of webmin hosting features across multiple domains much easier if you're going down that route.

http://www.webmin.com/virtualmin.html